# Using Excel to retrieve rows with black font color and not equal to 0 and based on a specific date, otherwise retrieve rows whose font color is red

Tags: excel, vba, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I will like to format the SharePoint file so that Power BI can only read the row font colour in red, otherwise black (if the values in black are out) - there will be a person updating this sheet. I will like to have this logic implemented into a new sheet.

[image: A small snippet of the dataset]

Unfortunately, from what I had researched, colour isn't data so Power BI can’t read them. So is there a way I can manually automate this in the Excel sheet?

I get the logic of how to do it, but I am unable to think of how to code it out.

Comment: First rule, color or formatting should not be used to transfer information/data it should be the result of data and only for visibility reasons. So the question you need to ask is **why** is this row red or black. The answer to that is the rule you need to apply on the data and that you can use to find your data. • Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. See [ask].

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f